# how to select closest or next div in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a php while loop in which there are multiple outputs of posts in whcih people can comment  now i want to hide the posts comments on which submit button is clicked
this is my code

```
 <form method="POST"  action="" >
                <div class="commentdiv">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username"  value="<?php echo $activeusername;?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid"  value="<?php echo $id3;?>">
          <textarea style=""  name="comment" id="comment" class="comment"  placeholder="  comment here"></textarea>
         <button type="button" style="background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #3897f0; font-weight:600;" class="submit" id="button_id">comment</button>

       </div>

          </form>

         <div id="comments" class="comments">
            <?php



$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment where post_id='$pixid' order by time2 desc limit 3";
$results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $commentid = $row['id'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $string = covertHashtags($comment);
    echo "<p class='written'>";
    echo "<a href='users2?id=".$row['user_id']."' style='color:black !important;'><b>".$row['username']."</b></a>";
    echo "  ".$string;
     $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM comment where id ='$commentid' and user_id='$id' order by comment desc limit 5 ";
$results3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($results3)>0) {

      echo "<div class='dropdown'>
  <img src='ellipsis.png' class='dots'>
  <div class='dropdown-content'>
    <br><p  class='delete' data-delete=".$commentid.">delete</p>
  </div>
</div>";

    } 
    else{
      echo "";
    }

     echo "</p>";  


  }
}else{
  echo "";
}

            ?>

          </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>



    <?php } ?>
```

this is all in a while loop so all output have same classes  now if i click on submit button of first post so i want the comment section of that post to dissapear not of all the posts only that particular posts's comment div

ive tried

```
$(this).closest('.comments').next('.comments');
```

and

```
 $(this).closest('.comments');
$(this).next('.comments');
```

but no luck nothing is happening in return plzz help me

Comment: [Traversing | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place where you come to get people to 'write a jquery for that'. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and (HINT) try it yourself first.

Comment: i tried many things  like $(this).closest('.comments').next('.comments').fadeOut();

Comment: Include what you tried in your question, complete

Comment: ^ along with a description of the result

Comment: done@PatrickQ @jaquarh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are in a `div` next to the `form` which contains the `button`.

So on click of that `button`, it would be:

```
$(this).closest("form").next(".comments").hide();
```

Comment: Why not just `$('#comments').slideToggle();` ? ID's are unique, `$(this)` isn't needed in this concept unless there was multiple buttons to hide multiple comment sections and then, OP would need to use a class not an id.

Comment: thnx alot buddy

Comment: @Jaquarh because this whole code is inside a loop and there are multiple buttons

Comment: @Jaquarh: In OP question, it is clearly mentionned: *i have a php while loop in which there are multiple outputs of posts in whcih people can comment...*

Comment: @dhruvsunoly in that case, `id="button_id"` within a loop is illegal for multiple buttons and will not work. An id has to be unique. `$('.submit').click()` will work with this answer however.

Comment: @Jaquarh: Correct... The `id` should not be defined in a loop unless a mechanism is added to make them unique. But using the class... It's ok. If the `id` stays and is duplicated but never used... Then it's just garbage that does not affect anything.

Comment: I did not see the `class='submit'` attached to the button, if he is adding an event listener to that, your solution is perfect. However, even if the id is not being used, best practice should be to keep them unique. +1 for answer anyway.